# Why does "hello" evaluate as true in a boolean condition?

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean

I have been doing work in C language as it was my first language from where i started.This time i was doing some coding with if else statement...and i find something which i cannot understand why it was happening.The code is as follow

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("How If - Else works\n");

    if("hello")
    {
        printf("Inside if\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Inside else\n");
    }

    getch();
}
```

In this the output was Inside if....i want to know how this thing get evaluated inside the if statement and is there any restriction to what we pass in the if statement.

Comment: Can you think of a time when '"hello"`, a pointer-to a constant string literal, will *ever* be NULL or equivalent to integer-zero ?

Comment: As an aside, this is true of every language I've ever encountered. The vast majority of languages treat (at least non-empty) strings as truthy values.

Comment: What a difference a title makes. The velocity of input on this question grew exponentially as soon as I committed that update. lol. =P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C doesn't really have boolean (`true` or `false`) values (C99 does, but my notes below still apply).

What C interprets as `false` is anything "0"; everything else is `true`;

so

```
if (0) {} else {printf("0 is false\n");}
if (NULL) {} else {printf("NULL is false\n");}
if (0.0) {} else {printf("0.0 is false\n");}
```

a literal string is interpreted as a pointer ... and it is pointing to real characters, so it's true

```
if (1) {printf("1 is true\n");} else {}
if (-1) {printf("-1 is true\n");} else {}
if ("hello") {printf("\"hello\" is true\n");} else {}
if (3.14159) {printf("3.14159 is true\n");} else {}
```

Interestingly an empty string or the string `"0"` or the character `'0'` is `true`

```
if ("") {printf("\"\" is true\n");} else {}
if ("0") {printf("\"0\" is true\n");} else {}
if ('0') {printf("'0' is true\n");} else {}
```

The NUL character (not NULL which is a pointer) has `int` value 0 and is `false`

```
if ('\0') {} else {printf("'\\0' is false\n");}
```

What happens when you have a real boolean construct is that the compiler emits code to convert that to `0` or `1`

```
if (a > b) /* whatever */;
// if a is greater than b, the compiler generated code will be something like
if (1) /* whatever */;
// otherwise, if a <= b, the generated code would look like
if (0) /* whatever */;
```

Comment: A literal string is a `char [N]`, where `N` is the length including the terminator. Like all arrays in C, the *value* is the address of the first element, which being non-NULL, will evaluate as true. This also explains empty string, `""`, since it is `char[1]` and again, its *value* is the address of the first (and only) element. Sorry, but I had real problems with "a literal string is interpreted as a pointer". It isn't. Its evaluated as an *address*. They're *not* the same.

Comment: Note: `if (-0.0)` is also false even though `-0.0` typically has a non-zero bit pattern.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `"0"` and `'0'` are not zero values, so they evaluate to true (since some people might misinterpret "anything '0'" as including the string).

Comment: an empty string like `""` is a `char *`, the value of `""[0]` (if it would work in c) is 0, but the value of the pointer is !=0

Comment: @WhozCraig In the context, pmg talks about it, the *expression* `"hello"` is a pointer. If it were to be an array , that would amount to constraint violation as the controlling expression of `if` must be a scalar type. The fact that the type of string literal is `char[N]` is not quite relevant here.

Comment: @BlueMoon "hello" is *not* a pointer. Its *value*, **like all arrays in C**, is the base address of its first element, and said-value is what is evaluated in the expression. Nowhere is a "pointer" involved in *any* of this. The *type* of said-value is `char (*)[N]`, which *is* a scaler type because its a pointer *type*; not because "hello" is a pointer; *it isn't*.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't think I said `"hello"` is a pointer but the *expression* is.

Comment: @BlueMoon then we're probably on the same page =P

Comment: @BlueMoon That expression isn't a pointer. That expression is of type `char [6]`, which is later implicitly converted to a pointer.

Answer (score 7):

The *(expression)* will evaluate to true if it can be converted to bool. "hello" is a string literal which evaluates to a pointer and since it's different than 0 it will result in true. A null pointer would return false.

The statement is valid if the expression can be implicitly converted to bool and this happens with most expressions: all scalar types (chars, arithmetic types, pointers, enums, etc) and also struct/class variables if they have an operator returning a scalar type. Functions returning no value at all (void) would generate an error.

Comment: There is a restriction: The value in the `if` condition has to be a scalar type. So, for example, you can't use a struct.

Comment: Being pedantic here but `"hello"` is a string literal which evaluates to a pointer to its first character in this context. It doesn't so always, for example, when used to initialize an array.

Comment: `"hello"` is an array of 6 char, not a pointer to a character string.

Answer (score 0):

If statement takes care of true and false only. So, if it's not false, everything else is a true.

False could be a 0, FALSE (bool), NULL. All the expressions get evaluated to one of true or false.

In your case, it is evaluates to true because it is not one of the false expressions.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have boolean datatype. As such, the statements requiring truth values accept that a value equal to `0` represents `false` and any other value represents `true`. `NULL` also evaluates to `false` (it is a macro defined as 0).

In your code `"hello"` is a non-null (different from 0) pointer to a string. This way, it will always be `true` inside `if` statements.

Anything that has a value can be used as an expression for this kind of statement.

Comment: Is not `_Bool` a C date type?  "An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0 and 1."  C spec 6.2.5 Types

Comment: @chux as far as I know, `_Bool` values are simply `#defines` with integer values. See [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/stdbool.h.html).

Comment: There are 2 `_Bool` values 0 and 1 - certainly not macros.  `<stdbool.h>` does have macros for `true` and `false` and `bool` which are the integer constant `1`, `0` and `_Bool`.  Try `_Bool x = 2; printf("%d\n", (int) x);`.  My compiler prints "1".  If `_Bool` was simply an `int`, I would expect "2".

Comment: @chux as per [this link](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/stdbool.h), they look pretty much like preprocessor directives to me. But it is certainly implementation-dependant. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: By "they", I assume you mean `false` and `true`.  But to use boolean variables in C, one does not even need to include the file you linked.  Just use `_Bool`, `0` and `1`, no need for `bool`, `false` and `true`.

Comment: @chux forget about it, I just read it is a keyword from C99 onwards. Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

A "string literal" in C represents a sequence of characters. This evaluates to a value other than zero or `NULL`; so the control flows into the if-loop.

Any independent expression can be evaluated inside the if conditional parentheses with the semntics as stated by the following in the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#expression):

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point after its evaluation. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value

So, the flow of the program goes into the `else` part if you do something like:

```
if(1,1,1,0) {
    printf("Inside if\n");
}
```

since the result of the expression takes the value of the last operand (`0`).

Answer (score -2):

Strings equate to a value True. Hence, your program flow goes into the `if` body and not the `else` body.

Comment: So do empty strings: `if ("") ` will test as true.

Comment: I dont have a C compiler to test it out. But the basic logic is if you try to convert a string to a boolean value, it would equate to a true value. Try it out.

Comment: Check out the answer by @pmg it defines the reason.

Comment: Believe me, I'm quite familiar with why it tests true.

Comment: "" is not NULL. Have a look at examples in answer given by @pmg