# What does this mean in C for the while loop?

Tags: c

```
int main(){

    char s[10];
    int t,n,i,a,w;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        w=0;
        scanf("%d%s",&n,s);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&a);
            if(a%2==0)
            w++;
        }
        if(n==1 && w==1 && strcmp(s,"Dee") == 0)
        printf("Dee\n");
        else
        printf("Dum\n");
    }
    return 0;}
```

`while(t--)`?
Is this `while(t=t-1)`?
That is never true for any given integer of `t`?

Comment: It's true as long as `t` is not 0.

Comment: In each loop execution, ```t``` will be decremented by 1 and loop will run till t is not 0.

Comment: @cLMaine - see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22362448/4386427

Answer (score 4):

```
while (t--) {
    ...
}
```

means evaluate whether `t` be true or false, then decrement `t` afterwards.  So if you input a value of `1` for `t`, then the above loop will actually iterate once, then terminate.

If, on the other hand, you had the following loop:

```
while (--t) {
    ...
}
```

if you entered `1` for `t` then the loop would not even execute once, because `t` would become zero before it is evaluated by the loop.

Answer (score 2):

`t=t-1` and `--t` are both same. `--t` is just a short notation.

`while()` exits if either it is `false` or `0`.Any number other than `0`(may be positive or negative) in the loop is always true After every loop execution/iteration `t` value gets decremented by 1 value. It continues till the value of `t` becomes `0` and exits the loop.

`t--` is called as post decrement. It first checks and then decrements the value.

`--t` is called as pre decrement. It first decrements the value and then checks.

Comment: Thanks, how long is it going to take me to become a good programmer?
Ive just finished the basics. Including pointers, math function etc...

Comment: @cLMaine Becoming a good programmer needs a lot of practice and strong basics.

Answer (score 2):

`while (t--)` is **almost** equivalent to `for(t = x; t>0; t--)` , except for the case `t<0`. when, `t<0`, `for` loop doesn't execute, but the `while` loop executes for unlimited time and the code crashes.

Here, `x` is the value by which `t` is initialized before running the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In a while loop **while(x){ ---- }**, if **x>=1** , then loop will be executed but when **x** becomes **<=0** , loop will be terminated.

So, in this question, let us say **t=2**, as in **while condition statement** the value is **2** , the loop will be executed but before that **t** is decremented to **1**. Similarly, **t** is decremented to **0** and loop will run one more time.

Now, 3rd time when loop tries to run value of t is already 0, so it will be terminated

Answer (score 0):

```
while(t--)
{
   //code
}
```

This loop will execute till the value of t becomes 0.